# Extract Data from Corrupted TerraSync file, Pathfinder can't correct & won't open

Tags: gps, trimble, pathfinder, corrupt, terrasync

I had an employee recording points for a project with a Trimble Geo XT 7 series receiver attached to a Zephyr 2 external antenna.  The receiver went to sleep between collecting episodes.  Upon attempting to re-open, the file came back as corrupted and TerraSync was unable to fix and open the file.  I have never had an unrecoverable corruption and didn't expect this to be a permanent problem. We stared a new file and finished collecting data.

However, now Pathfinder cannot fix and refuses to open the corrupted file.  I copied the corrupted file parts to a separate folder manually (Pathfinder won't transfer file).  I can open the individual files that show up in Windows Explorer (*.dd, *.gic, *.gip, *.gis, *giw, *.gix, *.obs, *.obx) in various programs (Notepad, Word, Excel), but only user-entered data (comments, notes, text fields from data dictionary form) show up as readable text.  The rest is various combinations of numbers, letters, and symbols.  I need to extract the coordinate data from this file, even if I can't postprocess and correct it.

Is there any way to translate the data displayed as symbols into text and numbers so that I can see the coordinates?

Comment: The various TerraSync files are a Trimble proprietary format.  I worked with TerraSync on Geo6000 and Geo7x for years (but not much recently), if the Pathfinder Office Check SSF File tool doesn't fix the problem, the only real option is to refer the problem to the Trimble MGIS Support guys.  That's not an option if you don't have a Support contract, and I'm not sure you can even buy TerraSync Support contracts anymore.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I can't even get Pathfinder to transfer the file and convert to .ssf so there is no .ssf to repair.

Comment: I have vague memories that the Support guys have a tool which takes that set of files you have and combines them into an SSF, same as the Pathfinder office transfer does but with some enhancements to deal with slightly corrupted files (not sure why they didn't just update the Pathfinder Office transfer routines. . . . )